# Getting an object by its key using GAE NDB API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Basically I'm trying to display a list of contacts and when the user clicks on one of them, the contact is displayed in another div.

My approach to the problem is to have a hidden input with the key, and then in the handler use the NDB API to retrieve the contact object by its key. But I'm not able to retrieve the object. I've tried some different solutions like making a Contact.query() and so on.. So far I've failed.

This is my Contact model:

```
class Contact(ndb.Model):
    cname = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    phone = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    date_add = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

In the template, I iterate over the contacts list, and every contact is a form:

```
    {% for contact in contacts %}
        <li>
            <form method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="act" value="display"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="key" value="{{contact.key.urlsafe()}}" />
                <input type="submit" value="{{ contact.cname }}"/>
            </form>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

This is my handler for the request

```
class Profile(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if users.get_current_user():
            contacts = get_contacts(users.get_current_user().user_id())
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
            template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('profile.html')
            template_values={
                'url':url,
                'url_linktext':url_linktext,
                'contacts':contacts,
            }
            if contacts:
                if self.request.get('act') == 'display':
                    dcontact = get_contact(self.request.get("key"))
                else:
                    dcontact = contacts[0]
                template_values['dcontact'] = dcontact
            self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

        else:
            self.redirect('/')
```

This is my last approach to the get_contact() function and the main problem in this case:

```
def get_contact(key):
    return Contact.get_by_id(key)
```

I would also appreciate some advice about this situations. I have done similar things in Django and for me it was easier. I'm still a little bit lost in webapp2 and GAE

Answer (score 1):

Well I fianlly got it. For those in similar situations I would recommend to read [NDB Entities and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities) It's a great documentation about using the Key in NDB API. I found it after I asked this question :/

The get_contact function() would be like this:

```
def get_contact(key):
    ckey = ndb.Key(urlsafe=key)
    return ckey.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to get retrieve an object from the datastore is to use the id.
You already tried yourself, but this is how it should be

```
def get_contact(key):
    return Contact.get_by_id(key.id())
```

A key has a `.id()` property that returns the id, this makes it possible to get an object with the key